# Why doesn't the "visit chat" link go straight to the chat room?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

If I press the **Visit Chat** button I end up in **[all rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)**.

Why not link directly to the [sci-fi chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/science-fiction-fantasy)?

This should also be the case for the **chat** word at the top of the screen (between name / badges + meta / main).

Comment: Are there other sites on SE that do that?

Comment: @DampeS8N - I have no idea - is that relevant? If the others have multiple chat rooms, then I understand it. But we have **one**.

Comment: @Gilles - I think you're a bit quick adding "status-declined". Why not wait a day or two to see if anyone else wants to contribute?

Comment: I marked it `status-declined` because it's a matter for SE staff, and [they already declined it in the past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68920/should-the-chat-link-of-a-se-2-0-site-take-you-to-the-site-specific-chat-room). If you'd like this decision revisited, I advise posting on that question.

Comment: @Gilles - thanks, I will only do that if the question gets a few upvotes.

Comment: @Wikis - this may not work because anytime someone starts a chat from a comment thread, that creates a new chat room. So we never are guaranteed to only have one chatroom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the case on every Stack Exchange site, including Server Fault and Super User, except Stack Overflow. To get to the chat room associated with this particular site, you need to click on the name of the chat room (`Science Fiction & Fantasy` for us, some sites have more than one).

This has come up before on the main meta site: [Should the 'chat' link of a SE 2.0 site take you to the site specific chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68920/should-the-chat-link-of-a-se-2-0-site-take-you-to-the-site-specific-chat-room). It's been tried and disliked.

Comment: it's not been tried here. It's the difference between "click" and "click, search, click". While there is only one room, it is more user friendly to have one click.

Comment: @Wikis, the single-click option is maybe a quarter of an inch below the multi-click option. Just get yourself into the habit of clicking the name of the chatroom instead of the Visit Chat button.

Comment: @Martha - oh thanks, Martha, I completely missed that!