# Why is "Community" bumping status-declined questions?

Tags: support, meta

Currently the most recently "active" question on meta is [Why doesn't the “visit chat” link go straight to the chat room?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/why-doesnt-the-visit-chat-link-go-straight-to-the-chat-room)

This question was asked and last edited on March 23rd.  The most recent answer is from March 23rd.  The most recent comment is from March 24th.  I believe that if there was a deleted answer then I would see that, and I can't see any.  It has the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag, so is of no interest to anyone any more.

If I understand correctly, the "Community" user will periodically "activate" older questions to promote them.  My guess is that is what happened here.  Shouldn't "status-declined" (and status-completed) questions be exempt from this?

Comment: I just accepted the answer. Maybe that will stop it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Community](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) [bumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped) questions that are unanswered, in the sense that they do not have an answer with a score of 1 or more. (I think that's the definition of “unanswered” used here, or maybe it's one upvote or more.) [The question in question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/why-doesnt-the-visit-chat-link-go-straight-to-the-chat-room) currently has a single answer with no vote either way, so it will keep being bumped.

The status tags such as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) have a different status from votes and acceptance. Votes and acceptance come from the community, whereas the status tags come from moderators and Stack Exchange staff. If a post is marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) but doesn't have an upvoted answer, it means that the community is unhappy with the moderator response, and therefore Community will keep raising the issue now and then, in case either party wants to reconsider.

Comment: ... or that nobody else *saw* the response..